# Android: doPost to server does not work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to create an Android app that process some data, gives output as array and sends this output to server. To do this, I make processing and sending in AsyncTask.

Here is my code:

```
//Params, progress, result
public class MachineLearningTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, int[]>{

public interface TaskListener {
    public void onFinished(int[] result);
}

private final static String TARGET_URL = "http://myURL";
private final static String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

private TaskListener taskListener;

private Context context;
private final ProgressDialog dialog;
private String activityTest;

public MachineLearningTask(Context ctx, String activity, TaskListener listener) {
    context = ctx;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    taskListener = listener;
    activityTest = activity;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Processing...");
    this.dialog.show();

}

@Override
protected int[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {

    // K-Means
    KMeansClustering kmeans = new KMeansClustering(params[0]);
    kmeans.mainKmeans();

    // K-NN
    KnnClustering knn = new KnnClustering();

    KmeansAndKnnAnalysis kka = new KmeansAndKnnAnalysis();
    kka.doAnalysis(kmeans,knn);

    int[] occurrenceKMeans = kka.getKmeansOccurrenceArray();
    int[] occurrenceKnn = kka.getKnnOccurrenceArray();

    // Google e Most
    GoogleAndMostAnalysis gma = new GoogleAndMostAnalysis();
    gma.Google_Most_Recognized_Activity();
    int[] occurrenceGoogle = gma.getGoolgeRecognizedActivity();
    int[] occurrenceMost = gma.getMostRecognizedActivity();

    FileOperation fo = new FileOperation();
    fo.writeResult(activityTest, occurrenceKMeans, occurrenceKnn, occurrenceGoogle, occurrenceMost);

    int idActivityKMeans = gma.findMax(occurrenceKMeans);
    int idActivityKnn = gma.findMax(occurrenceKnn);
    int idActivityGoogle = gma.findMax(occurrenceGoogle);
    int idActivityMost = gma.findMax(occurrenceMost);

    int[] matrixOccurrence = {idActivityKMeans, idActivityKnn, idActivityGoogle, idActivityMost};

    JSONObject dataToSend = algorithmFeedback(matrixOccurrence);
    JSONObject test = doFunc(dataToSend);

    Log.d("HTTP_POST", dataToSend.toString());

    return matrixOccurrence;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onPostExecute(int[] result) {

    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    if (taskListener != null) {
        taskListener.onFinished(result);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/* {"result":[
                {"algorthm":"Kmeans", "readAct":"camminare", "trueAct":"camminare"},
                {"algorthm":"Knn", "readAct":"camminare", "trueAct":"camminare"},
                {"algorthm":"Google", "readAct":"camminare", "trueAct":"camminare"},
                {"algorthm":"Most", "readAct":"camminare", "trueAct":"camminare"}
            ]}*/
private JSONObject algorithmFeedback(int[] result){

    FileOperation fo = new FileOperation();
    String algorithm;
    String knowActivity;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject item;

    try{

        for (int i = 0 ; i<result.length; i++){
            item = new JSONObject();
            algorithm = fo.getAlgorithmByIndex(i);
            knowActivity = fo.idToActivity(result[i], algorithm);
            item.put("algorithm", algorithm);
            item.put("readAct", knowActivity);
            item.put("trueAct", activityTest);
            array.put(item);
        } 
            obj.put("result", array);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}

private Boolean checkNetworkConnection(){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //Non è possibile connettersi
        return false;
    }
}

private JSONObject doFunc(JSONObject params) {
    JSONObject serverResponse = null;

    if(checkNetworkConnection() == true) {
        Log.d("OK", "OK");
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(TARGET_URL);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d("OK1", "OK1");
            //To upload data to a web server, configure the connection for output using setDoOutput(true).
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset="+CHARSET);
            Log.d("OK2", "OK2");
            //For best performance, you should call either setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int) 
            //when the body length is known in advance, or setChunkedStreamingMode(int) when it is not. 
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            //------------Request-----------
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            writeStream(out, params);
            Log.d("OK3", "OK3");
            //-----------Response----------
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            serverResponse = readStream(in);
            Log.d("OK4", "OK4");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                serverResponse = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                serverResponse = null;
        } finally {
             urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return serverResponse;
}

private void writeStream(OutputStream out, JSONObject obj){
    String clientData = obj.toString();
    try {
        out.write(clientData.getBytes(CHARSET));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JSONObject readStream(InputStream in) {
    String serverResponse = in.toString();
    JSONObject out = null;

    try {
        in.close();
        out = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out = null;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out = null;
    }

    return out;
}
}
```

When i run this app, it works fine until this line of code:

```
Log.d("OK2", "OK2");
```

After this point, the app shows the ProgressDialog and does not do anything. 
After one minute the app crashes.

Here there is a part of stack trace:

```
11-27 20:05:39.921: D/OK(28449): OK
11-27 20:05:39.924: D/OK1(28449): OK1
11-27 20:05:39.925: D/OK2(28449): OK2
11-27 20:05:39.931: I/System.out(28449): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-27 20:05:39.924: I/System.out(28449): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-27 20:06:40.654: I/Timeline(28449): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c079afe time:13153897
11-27 20:07:11.384: V/ActivityThread(28449): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{8b423d2 token=android.os.BinderProxy@c079afe {org.most/com.unipa.activityrecognition.Experiment}} show : true
11-27 20:07:12.594: D/ViewRootImpl(28449): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.4 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:434)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:105)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1331)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1410)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:466)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.unipa.algorithm.MachineLearningTask.doFunc(MachineLearningTask.java:195)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.unipa.algorithm.MachineLearningTask.doInBackground(MachineLearningTask.java:101)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at com.unipa.algorithm.MachineLearningTask.doInBackground(MachineLearningTask.java:1)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
11-27 20:07:49.004: W/System.err(28449):    ... 24 more
11-27 20:07:49.004: D/HTTP_POST(28449): {"result":[{"algorithm":"KMEANS","readAct":"Fermo","trueAct":"Fermo"},{"algorithm":"KNN","readAct":"Fermo","trueAct":"Fermo"},{"algorithm":"GOOGLE","readAct":"still","trueAct":"Fermo"},{"algorithm":"MOST","readAct":"staticoSulTavolo","trueAct":"Fermo"}]}
11-27 20:07:49.014: D/ViewRootImpl(28449): #3 mView = null
11-27 20:07:49.014: D/Occurrence(28449): [0, 0, 0, 0]
11-27 20:07:56.264: I/Timeline(28449): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c079afe time:13229504
```

Can you help me to find where i'm wrong?

**Solution:**

**The problem is that *Windows firewall blocks the port* where i try to connect.

For this reason the connection is in time out. 
To resolve this problem in Windows just create an exception in Windows firewall.**

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I edit my post. @Emmanuel

Comment: Your connection is timing out. Are you sure 192.168.1.4:8080 is the right IP?

Comment: I'm using tomcat server. It is my first time I use it and i don't know if i'm doing it correctly. I downloaded xampp and then i started tomcat server from button. When i enter in server, in main page the IP address is 192.168.1.4:8080 and i use it in my app. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 192.168.1.4:8080 is correct IP. I understand what is the problem. I run Tomcat in another pc and all works fine. The problem is that Windows10 firewall blocks the port where i try to connect. For this reason the connection is in time out. To resolve this problem in Windows, I must create an exception in my firewall.